Got PDFUAConformanceException while converting HTML to PDF using java Itext 8.0.4
PdfDocument pdfDoc =  new PdfUADocument(new PdfWriter(dest),
                new PdfUAConfig(PdfUAConformanceLevel.PDFUA_1, "PDF", "en-US"));

Got:

com.itextpdf.pdfua.exceptions.PDFUAConformanceException: Document does not contain valid lang entry

As we are setting language to en-US, there shouldn't be any issue but got the above error.

Can you create a minimal reproduceable example with the html you are using?
Because your code seems ok.

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.
